# How to destructure to reference to value instead of reference to borrow?

Tags: rust

How to rewrite what follows to have it all in one line, in function signature:

```
fn process(tup: &mut (u32,u32,&mut image::Luma<u8>)) {
  let &mut (x,y, _) = tup;
  let ref mut pixel = *tup.2;
```

I got as far as:

```
fn process(&mut (x,y, ref mut pixel): &mut (u32,u32,&mut image::Luma<u8>)) {
```

but that's not exact equivalent because I no longer can do:

```
*pixel = image::Luma([i as u8]);
```

inside the function, that I could do when I had temporary `tup` binding.

Fails with:

```
src\main.rs:43:14: 43:36 note: expected type `&mut image::Luma<u8>`
src\main.rs:43:14: 43:36 note:    found type `image::Luma<u8>`
```

I also tried:

```
process(&mut (x, y, pixel): &mut (u32,u32,&mut image::Luma<u8>))
```

but this fails with:

```
src\main.rs:23:12: 23:29 error: cannot move out of borrowed content [E0507]
src\main.rs:23 fn process(&mut (x,y, pixel): &mut (u32,u32,&mut image::Luma<u8>)) {
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src\main.rs:23 fn process(&mut (x,y, pixel): &mut (u32,u32,&mut image::Luma<u8>)) {
                                     ^~~~~
```

Basically what I need is pattern that can destructure reference to borrowed value from a borrow.

Comment: I'd like to point that in this specific case, you should be able to write `process((x, y, pixel): (u32, u32, &mut X))`. The outer `&mut` (on both sides) is useless here.

Comment: Does not compile without it due to type mismatch: `src\main.rs:72:33: 72:34 note: expected type (u32, u32, &mut image::Luma<u8>)
src\main.rs:72:33: 72:34 note:    found type &mut (u32, u32, &mut _)`

I also can't deference at the call site because `cannot move out of borrowed content`. Would work if tuple third element wasn't a borrow.

Comment: Damned... that a sticky situation you found yourself in!

Comment: Just tried to use https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/image with their example 6.2 (drawing Julia fractal) and extract calculation to separate function. ... The more I fall, the more I learn. Anyways, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fn process(&mut (x,y, &mut ref mut pixel): &mut (u32,u32,&mut image::Luma<u8>)) {
```

This pattern `&mut (x,y, &mut ref mut pixel)` makes the `pixel` mutable reference to borrowed value.

`&mut` in `&mut ref mut pixel` unwraps the value from the borrow before `ref mut` makes the `pixel` reference to it.

I found this solution after looking here: http://rustbyexample.com/flow_control/match/destructuring/destructure_pointers.html