# How to apply reduce to chunks (coming from a borrowed reference to an array)?

Tags: rust

How can I make use of functional patterns without incurring in borrowing problems? The solution proposed by the compiler leads to another error (`expected array` [u8; 3]`, found '&[u8]'`) and it goes on from one error to another different error, indefinitely.
Some related code seem overly complicated for such a simple task like in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37926547/9681577).

```
use reduce::Reduce;

/// Take an array representing a sequence of 3-tuples and fold it through an arbitrary sandwich logic.
fn sandwich(lst: &[u8])->[u8; 3]{
    lst.chunks(3).reduce(|x, y| [x[0], y[1], x[0]]).unwrap()
}
/*
3  |     lst.chunks(3).reduce(|x, y| [x[0], y[1], x[0]]).unwrap()
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                                 |
   |                                 expected `&[u8]`, found array `[u8; 3]`
   |                                 help: consider borrowing here: `&[x[0], y[1], x[0]]`
*/
```

The best compilable code I could write was this convoluted one, giving up [reduce](https://crates.io/crates/reduce) at all:

```
fn sandwich2(lst: &[u8])->[u8; 3]{
    let mut r: [u8; 3] = lst[..].try_into().unwrap();
    for i in (3..lst.len()).step_by(3) {
        let y = &lst[i..i + 3];
        r = [r[0], y[1], r[0]];
    }
    r
}
```

Please note that sandwich is just an example to illustrate the problem (that does nothing actually smart). I expect an external much more complex function instead of that lambda.

Comment: what is `reduce`? I don't recognize that from the standard library or the itertools crate.

Comment: @kmdreko I edited to add reference.  "`reduce` gives Iterators a reduce function that is similar to fold but without an initial value."

Comment: `reduce` expects that both parameters of the closure and its return value all have the same type. But `chunks` returns slices and `sandwich` returns an array, so you will need a conversion at some point. Possibly: `lst.chunks (3).cloned().reduce (|x, y| [x[0], y[1], x[0]])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to somehow take ownership of the values into a required `[u8; 3]`.

Maybe as this example using the `iterator_fold_self` feature (as per today nightly):

```rust
#![feature(iterator_fold_self)]

/// Take an array representing a sequence of 3-tuples and reduce it through an arbitrary sandwich logic.
fn sandwich(lst: &[u8]) -> [u8; 3] {
    lst.chunks(3)
        .map(|x| [x[0], x[1], x[2]])
        .reduce(|x, y| [x[0], y[1], x[0]])
        .unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let test_set = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];
    println!("{:?}", sandwich(&test_set));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1a02988ed4758467f13d9ae0d1d2d244)

You can use `try_into`(from this [famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50080940/1695172)) to get an owned slice:

```rust
fn sandwich(lst: &[u8]) -> [u8; 3] {
    lst.chunks(3)
        .map(|x| -> [u8; 3] { x.try_into().unwrap() } )
        .reduce(|x, y| [x[0], y[1], x[0]])
        .unwrap()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fc34a5ba8590243b3e979a90de34470d)

Comment: That works. However, how can I take ownership when  the chunk size is large, say 200?

Comment: @olyk, for that you can map another function that copies the content of the referenced slice into another owned one. You can find how to do it around SO too :)

Comment: The ` -> [u8; 3] ` part is novelty to me and solve basically all my problems. Probably I need to finish the book reading every single paragraph before attempting to effectively program anything real ...

Comment: [Another option from the answers from your link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38253365/9681577). Will be worth a try in terms of performance.

Comment: @olyk, yes, array_ref may be useful. I tried to stick to the std though