# How to use Result correctly?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to return ok if everything went well and return the error code if something went wrong, but it doesn't work:

```rust
mod reader {
    /*uses*/
    enum FileError {
        FileNotFound,
        PgnInvalid,
    }
    fn read_game(file_path: &str) -> Result<BufferedReader<File>, FileError> {
        let f = File::open(file_path)?;
        match f {
            Err(e) => FileError::FileNotFound,
            Ok(file) => {
                let r = BufferedReader::new(file)?;
                match r {
                    Err(e) => FileError::PgnInvalid,
                    Ok(reader) => reader,
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
 mismatched types [E0308] expected `Result<BufferedReader<File>, FileError>`, found `FileError`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Result` is an enum which can be one of two variants: either `Ok(..)` or `Err(..)`. When returning a result, you need to specify which variant you're returning. Right now you're just returning a `FileError` or a `BufferedReader<File>` causing the types of the match arms to conflict, and also conflicting with the return type. Instead what you can do is map the error type using `Result`'s [`map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err) function, and apply the `?` (read "try") operator to return early with the error variant upon encountering an error.

```rs
fn read_game(file_path: &str) -> Result<BufferedReader<File>, FileError> {
    let f = File::open(file_path).map_err(|_| FileError::FileNotFound)?;
    BufferedReader::new(f).map_err(|_| FileError::PgnInvalid)
}
```

You can read more about result [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/result.html), and I'd also recommend checking out the [section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html) in the book about enums.

Comment: What is `|_|` ?

Comment: ok, now I have `method not found in BufferedReader<std::fs::File>`

Comment: That's signaling the start of a [closure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html), and you can read more about `_` on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925198/what-does-mean-in-type-errors-in-rust)

Comment: Where is the type `BufferedReader` coming from? `std` has [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) whose `new` method doesn't return a `Result`.

Comment: okay, this thing doesn't return a result

Answer (score 0):

To return a `Result` you need to return one of its enum values, either `Ok` or `Err`. So your code could be:

```rust
fn read_game(file_path: &str) -> Result<BufferedReader<File>, FileError> {
    let f = File::open(file_path);
    match f {
        Err(e) => Err(FileError::FileNotFound),
        Ok(file) => {
            let r = BufferedReader::new(file);
            // BufferedReader::new does not return a `Result`.
            // Wrap the reader in `Ok` to return a `Result`.
            Ok(r)
        }
    }
}
```

As a shortcut the `?` operator unwraps any `Ok` value and returns any `Err` values for you. So you can add `?` and remove the `match` to get this almost working code:

```rust
fn read_game(file_path: &str) -> Result<BufferedReader<File>, FileError> {
    let f = File::open(file_path)?;
    let r = BufferedReader::new(file);
    Ok(r)
}
```

The problem with this code is that the returned `Result` does not support a `std::io::Error` (the error type from `open`). You can either return a `Result<BufferedReader<File>, std::io::Error>` or you can map the error type to the type you do support:

```rust
fn read_game(file_path: &str) -> Result<BufferedReader<File>, FileError> {
    let f = File::open(file_path).map_err(|_| FileError::FileNotFound)?;
    let r = BufferedReader::new(f);
    Ok(r)
}
```